# problems coding a caesar cipher

Tags: python, list, encryption

I need to code a caesar cipher code for a project at school and I ran into a bug that I cant fix...

When I ender the same letter twice it does not code it correctly..

can anyone help?

here is the code:

```
#This is a ceser code +2

letters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','S','Y','Z']
message = input('enter a message to eyncrypt in capital letters')
message_incrypt = str()

for x in message:
    if x in letters:
        x = letters.index(x)
        x = letters.pop(x+2)
        message_incrypt = message_incrypt + str(x)
    else:
        print ('you can input only capital letters')


print (message_incrypt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `pop`. This removes the value from the list. (
[Python docs on `pop`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists))

e.g.

```
arr = [1,2,3]
arr.pop(1)
```

Will make `arr` be `[1,3]`

You can just get the value from indexing the array

e.g.

```
arr = [1,2,3]
val = arr[1]
```

This misunderstanding is most noticeable when you do the same letter twice, because the first one will modify the array, so the second one will give a different result.